# The value on the Context Provider doesn't change

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

So, I'm learning about React Context and try to implement it by creating an auth state for my React Native app. I tried following this [Ben Awad's repo](https://github.com/benawad/react-navigation-v5-tutorial/tree/17757cdd427f7c044430946eb069695431c1b4d9). This is what I've got so far:

```
// AuthContext.tsx
export const AuthContext = createContext<{
  user: null | string;
  login: () => void;
}>({
  user: null,
  login: () => {},
});

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }: Props) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<null | string>(null);
  const { user: contextUser } = useContext(AuthContext);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        user,
        login: () => {
          setUser("My Name");
          console.log("Auth Provider pressed");
          console.log("user (state) " + user);
          console.log("contextUser (context) " + contextUser);
        },
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

// Navigation.tsx
export const Navigation = ({}: Props) => {
  const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);

  return (
    <AuthProvider>
        {user ? <HomeScreen /> : <Button />}
    </AuthProvider>

// Button.tsx
export const Button = ({}: Props) => {
  const { login } = useContext(AuthContext);

  return (
    <View>
        <Touchable
          onPress={login}
        >
          <Text style={styles.container}>Submit</Text>
        </Touchable>
    </View>
  )
```

The AuthProvider has 2 values. `user` which is obtained from the `useState()`. And, `login` which calls the `setUser` to change the `user` on the `useState()` and thus **should** change the `user` on the first Provider value.

The onPress on Button will call `login()` from the AuthProvider. The `login()` on the AuthProvider will trigger `setUser` to change the `user` on the `useState()` value from null to "My Name". Until this part, it works as expected.

But, even though the button successfully changes the `user` value on the `useState()`. It doesn't change the `user` (changed to `contextUser` for "debugging" purpose) on the Context, no mater how many times I click the button, the `contextUser` will always be null.

**Tl;dr**: user value on AuthProvider doesn't change after the button is pressed. But, user on useState changes.

So, what happened? What did I do wrong? Anyone has any idea how to fix this? I've stuck with this issue for the last few hours and googled more about this. My code is similar to theirs (I compared mine with other people's code that also uses context & auth), but somehow this code doesn't work.

Anyway, on Navigation, it should also automatically re-renders (to be HomeScreen) after the user value on Context is changed to non-null. I still haven't tested if it'll work (well, the user value never changes). Anyone could also review it to see if it could also run as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are consuming the context `const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);` in a component (`Navigation`) which is not a child of the `AuthProvider`.

At the moment your Navigation component is only receiving the context's default state. If you add a `console.log` to your context default state's `login` method, you will see this executed, rather than the contextual `login` method which is returned as the context's value. E.g:

```
// AuthContext.tsx
export const AuthContext = createContext<{
  user: null | string;
  login: () => void;
}>({
  user: null,
  login: () => {
    // this will run if there is no context provider when being called
    console.log('i am not working as expected')
  },
});
```

However, your Button component is receiving the full context, since it is a child of the Provider, and is updating the state.

If you move the `AuthProvider` "up a level" so that it is a parent of your `Navigation` component, then the Navigation component will also receive the updated context data.

E.g:

```
const Wrapper = () => (
  <AuthProvider> 
    <Navigation />
  </AuthProvider>
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That makes sense now. I just wrapped the Navigation inside the Provider and place it in the App and now it runs as expected!